# How to pick specific values from dataframes stored in a dictionary matching a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, multipleselection

I have several big dataframes, each for an data ID with columns like 'speed', 'acceleration', 'time'.
These dataframes are stored in a dict with their matching ID as key.
Now i need to pick as example the 'speed' value at time x for each ID and add it to a list.

With my current code i can already manage that.
My actual problem is that the value list is either a list of lists containing a single value each or a list containing not only the values but also additional data that i do not want.

Data example:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Speed': [2.187180, 2.626560, 1.727620], 
                        'Speed Unit': ['um/s', 'um/s', 'um/s'],
                        'Acceleration': [0.00000, 4.08670, 6.42011],
                        'Acceleration Unit': ['um/s^2', 'um/s^2', 'um/s^2'], 
                        'Time': [1, 2, 3],
                        'TrackID': [1000000002, 1000000002, 1000000002]})

    bigDict = {ID1:df1,ID2:df2,...}
```

Code1:

```
for ID in bigDict.keys():
    vlist.append(bigDict[ID].loc[bigDict[ID]['Time'] == 3, 'Speed'].tolist())
```

This generates me my desired list of values but each value is in a list itself. If I don't use .tolist()

Code2:

```
for ID in bigDict.keys():
    vlist.append(bigDict[ID].loc[bigDict[ID]['Time'] == 3, 'Speed'])
```

I get the already mentioned list containing additional data

Results code 1:

```
[[1.7276200000000002], [2.47614], [8.48897], [10.7183], [14.4901],
[14.1587], [2.4992799999999997], [0.8659370000000001], [5.92513], 
[3.44153], [3.0253099999999997], [4.887919999999999], [8.53875], 
    ...]
```

Results code 2:

```
[365    1.72762
Name: Speed, dtype: float64, 367    2.47614
Name: Speed, dtype: float64, 368    8.48897
Name: Speed, dtype: float64, 371    10.7183
Name: Speed, dtype: float64, 369    14.4901
...]
```

Comment: Can u plzz show us some eg of ur i/p data set

Comment: Section with data example added

Comment: Option 1: add a `[0]` at the end of code1, Option 2: replace `.append` with `.extend` (also code 1)

Comment: You can use `vlist.append(bigDict[ID].Speed.loc[bigDict[ID]['Time'] == 3])`.

Comment: @Mstaino Thanks a lot, your solution worked fine for me. Had to include try to cope with empty values but now it runs nicely.

Comment: @a_guest Did not work for me produces the same output as my code 2. But thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my demo program, hope it helps.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame([[12,34,7],[13,45,9]],columns=["speed","acct","time"])
df2=pd.DataFrame([[17,44,3],[120,45,8]],columns=["speed","acct","time"])
df3=pd.DataFrame([[456,90,8],[13,45,3]],columns=["speed","acct","time"])

 #dictionary of dfs
d={123:df1,890:df2,567:df3}

#list 
l=[]

#use extend instead of append
 #append will add the series to list.
   #extends will break the series and add the values 
for i in d.keys():
    l.extend(d[i][d[i]["time"]==3]["speed"])

print(l)
```

Comment: My program is very much different from urs, but it will help u to solve ur problem!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your code works fantastic for me. It doesn't evan need "try: except:" to cope with missing values, like the above mentioned solution. The extend command is rly nice and will help me in the future i think ^^